# How do I write to a json File in angular?

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to write some data from 4 drop down lists (making a fake service) that when I press submit it writes the 4 away to a JSON file.

A little more context:

I am making a pizza application (like dominos) to learn angular. I have been tasked with after you press order pizza it sends the pizza to a manage order screen. When I press submit I want my pizza to be sent to my fake service which just saves it to a JSON and then the manage order screen should then read the json to populate that screen.

Comment: Angular applications run in the browser. They can't write to files. Than can send HTTP requests to the server where they come from, though, and the REST services running on the server can do whatever they want.

Comment: I suggest you learning about HttpClient: https://angular.io/guide/http . You can send your request (json) to the server and store it on serverside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot write to a file using Javascript on the client side. Consider a server side library.